# Why both `stylesheet_link_tag` and `stylesheet_pack_tag` are needed to install bootstrap?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-5

I have gone through this [article](https://medium.com/daily-web-dev/use-bootstrap-4-with-ruby-on-rails-6-and-webpack-fe7300604267) to install bootstrap in ruby-on-rails app.

And I noticed that there are `stylesheet_link_tag` and `stylesheet_pack_tag` for css. I wonder why both is needed, isn't one is enough in `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`?

```
<head>
  <title>BootstrapDemo</title>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= csp_meta_tag %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
</head>
```

Answer (score 4):

`stylesheet_pack_tag 'application'` is a `webpacker` helper method, it loads styles that are imported in `app/javascript/packs/application.js`. If you set up bootstrap in `app/javascript/` then pack tags are required.

`stylesheet_link_tag 'application'` is a `sprockets` helper method, it loads styles from `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css`. If you don't use that file for anything then stylesheet_link_tag can be removed.

```rb
app/
  assets/                # used by sprockets aka rails asset pipeline
    stylesheets/
      application.css    # stylesheet_link_tag 'application'
    javascripts/
      application.js     # javascript_include_tag 'application'

  javascript/            # used by rails webpacker
    packs/
      application.js     # javascript_pack_tag 'application'
                         # stylesheet_pack_tag 'application' # => includes 'styles.css'
    stylesheets/
      styles.css         # must be imported in packs/application.js
```

Comment: But according to this [issue](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/pull/2608), the `pack_tags` is not needed due to inconsistent behaviour

Comment: looks like that issue was fixed. problem was a different config between production and development in webpack.yml. if `extract_css: true` then `stylesheet_pack_tag` outputs a link to css. if `extract_css: false` then `javascript_pack_tag` inlines the styles in the <head> tag. this doesn't affect `stylesheet_link_tag`.